# How to get the content of a selected item in another fragment

Tags: android-fragments

I'm using fragments in my android application , my problem is that i can't send the content of a selected item of a list view to another fragment.I used getItemAtPosition method but i couldn't continue. 
this the code of the first fragment :

lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

```
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                             FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                Fragment fragmentACharger = null;   

                                Client c=(Client) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                                fragmentACharger = new Consulter_Client1();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.container,fragmentACharger).commit(); 
                            return false;
                        }

                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {         
            OnRestaurant_Click(position, );

        }
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void OnRestaurant_Click(position, ) {
    final MealDetails_Fragment fragment = new MealDetails_Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("position, ", position, );       
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.Layout_FindMacros, fragment)
            .addToBackStack("find to Restaurant_click")
            .commit();
}
```